# Python - Write file to sftp in ansi

Tags: python-3.x

I want to recover a csv file from an azure blob and tranfer it to a sftp server with ansi encoding.

When I test to write In local (intead of sftp) i have the expected behavior with this code :

```
sas_url_blob_file = parameters.connection_string_datalake.split("?")[0]+"/"+batch.name+"?"+parameters.connection_string_datalake.split("?")[1]
df = pd.read_csv(sas_url_blob_file, dtype=str, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep=';')

with open(file, "w", encoding='ansi') as f:     
    df.to_csv(f, index = False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar="\\", header = True, sep=';', line_terminator='\r\n')
```

But when I use paramiko lib (to write on sftp) i can't indicate the desired target encoding.

```
sftp_server = ssh_server.open_sftp()

with sftp_server.open(filename, 'w', encoding='ansi' --> Is not an option !!!) as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index = False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar="\\", header = True, sep=';', line_terminator='\r\n')
```

I tried also to open sftp file in write binary mode and define encoding into command "to_csv" --> OK to write in local but no on sftp (freeze or very long ...)

```
with sftp_server.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index = False, encoding='ansi', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar="\\", header = True, sep=';', line_terminator='\r\n')
```

How I can write easily with ansi encoding into the sftp server ?

Thank you in advance !

How I can write easily with ansi encoding into the sftp server ?

Comment: by "ANSI" do you mean "windows-1254" or "us7ascii"?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes Windows 1254 or cp1252 for example.